# Mongoose cast to number failed for value '$sum'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using Mongoose 5.12.7 with mongo 4.4.5, and I am trying to update the total points in the object, it should be the sum of the easy, medium, hard and extreme points.

[This is currently how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbbGj.png)

This is the update query:

```
maths_results.updateOne({ "Id":_id},{$set: {"totalPoints":[{$sum:["$easy.points","$medium.points","$hard.points","$extreme.points"]}]}})
```

Here is the Mongoose Schema:

```
    const Maths_results_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Id:{type:String,
    required:true},
    userName:{type:String,
        required:true},
    totalPoints:Number,
    easy:{points:Number,
        speed:Number,testsTaken:[
            {Time:Number,
            correct:Number,
            date:{type:Date,
                default:Date.now}
    }]},
    medium:{points:Number,
        speed:Number,testsTaken:[
            {Time:Number,
            correct:Number,
            date:{type:Date,
                default:Date.now}
    }]},
    hard:{points:Number,
        speed:Number,testsTaken:[
            {Time:Number,
            correct:Number,
            date:{type:Date,
                default:Date.now}
    }]},
    extreme:{points:Number,
        speed:Number,testsTaken:[
            {Time:Number,
            correct:Number,
            date:{type:Date,
                default:Date.now}
    }]}})
```

Though I get an error:

```
CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "[
  {
    '$sum': [
      '$easy.points',
      '$medium.points',
      '$hard.points',
      '$extreme.points'
    ]
  }
]" at path "totalPoints"
at model.Query.exec
at model.Query.Query.then
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"[\n' +
    '  {\n' +
    "    '$sum': [\n" +
    "      '$easy.points',\n" +
    "      '$medium.points',\n" +
    "      '$hard.points',\n" +
    "      '$extreme.points'\n" +
    '    ]\n' +
    '  }\n' +
    ']"',
  kind: 'Number',
  value: [ { '$sum': [Array] } ],
  path: 'totalPoints',
  reason: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value
```

Comment: regular update query wont allow internal field as input/value of another internal field, you can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2

Comment: In the Mongo shell the query works successfully so it really seem like a mongoose issue?

Comment: it is impossible to work this query in shell or anywhere, no its not mongoose error. the syntax is wrong it wont support internal fields.

Comment: True thanks! I spotted that I missed the "[" before the $set

Comment: yes that is i referred you in first comment it is called update with aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Now fixed, I was missing the first "[" before $set, correct query is:

````
maths_results.updateOne({ "Id":_id},[{$set: {"totalPoints":[{$sum:["$easy.points","$medium.points","$hard.points","$extreme.points"]}]}}])```
````